# Von Neumann Algebra decomposition

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, operators, representation-theory, density-operator

I am trying to understand the Von Neumann decomposition, according to which every Von Neumann Algebra can be uniquely decomposed as integral (or direct sum) of factors. More specifically, I am trying to connect (if possible) the Von Neumann decomposition to the GNS theorem. Can someone please help me answer the following questions?

1. Given a normal state, is it true that its GNS representation is always a factor state?
2. Is it possible that the algebra obtained by applying GNS theorem on a irreducible state is not a factor?
3. Physically speaking, why is Von Neumann decomposition important?